# SQL Server / T-SQL: Does CHOOSE evaluate all results, or just the result being returned?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, control-flow, sql-server-2017

Does a `CHOOSE` statement cause the server to evaluate *ALL* of the possible results?
Or does the server only evaluate the result that was chosen?

I'm in a situation where I have a list of a dozen possible outcomes, based on the integer values 1 through 12 - but the results are very long mathematical processes, and I don't want the server to waste time evaluating all 12 of them, just to pick only one result to return.

For example :

```
CHOOSE ( 2 , LongOperation1 ( ) , LongOperation2 ( ) , LongOperation3 ( ) , etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that it does not perform all the computations. Both examples below contain a 1/0 option, but only 1 of the statements below will error on a divide by zero error:

```
select CHOOSE(2, 1, 1+4, 1/0)
```

vs

```
select CHOOSE(2, 1, 1/0, 1+4)
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland Not sure if you are disagreeing with this answer? If you are, please add your own. The reason I included both examples is to show that if CHOOSE() evaluated all the indices, both would error. Instead, only the 2nd one errors.

Comment: never mind +1 didn't notice before the first query also has `1/0` blame it on the time it's late over here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Added that in the post in case we have any other sleepy heads around here.